# read data in specific column and row of a text file

Tags: python, text, row, line

I Have a text file which contain 3 columns and 20000 rows.
I like to know what should I do to get the specific data (for example) in row 1000 and column 2?
My first column is formatted like AAAA and my second column is a number like 1234.
I tried this solution but I got an error based on my first column being letters
I would like to define a variable which contains my data at the end:

```
with open ('my_file') as f:
    for x , line in eumerate(f):
         if x = 1000:
             numfloat = map(float , line.split())
             print numfloat[1]
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'row' in a text file?

Comment: Does this mean that your first row is alphabets and second row is numbers? Does each line contain 3 rows?

Comment: Do you mean "column" instead of "row" here?

Comment: Same as @roganjosh, I understand there's a little language difference, but it would help us out to say column instead of row. anyway, are your columns always separated by spaces or some other character?

Comment: sry for mistype. yes I mean column. and the columns are separated with space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `float()` on something that contains letters.  this happens when you call:

```
numfloat = map(float , line.split())
```

You need to tell us the exact output that you are looking for but here is one possible solution

```
num_float = map(float, line.split()[1])

or better yet

num_float = float(line.split()[1])
```

This will only get you the middle column, I'm not certain if you need the entire row or not.

Additionally, as noted below, you need to change `=` to `==` in your if statement.  `=` is for assigment, `==` is for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

make '=' to '==' at line 3 of your code

```
with open('my_file', 'r') as f:
    for x, line in enumerate(f):
        if x == 1000:
            print float(line.split()[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

with open('my_file', 'r') as f:
    for x, line in enumerate(f):
        if x == 1000: 
            array = re.split('(\d+)',line) # array=['AAAA','123'] if line='AAAA123'
            print array[1] # your required second row.
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.